# Can AWS Toolkit in Eclipse be used with localstack?

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, localstack, aws-toolkit

For local development, I was hoping to set up a localhost profile for AWS Toolkit that I could then use in Eclipse to interact with resources on localstack, but I'm at a loss to set this up. There is a local(localhost) option in AWS Toolkit, but I don't see how it would know what endpoints to access for the various services in localstack.

It seems like a relatively logical thing to want to do, or do I have to do all my interaction with the aws (or awslocal) cli?

Comment: I'm also trying to get AWS Toolkit connected to LocalStack. I suspect it has to do with the `--endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566` that is required to talk to LocalStack using the AWS CLI. The Toolkit in Eclipse doesn't appear to have any way to set that.